# How to read xlsx file in protect mode to R

Tags: r

I am wondering if there is a way to import data from a xlsx file in protect mode without opening the xlsx file first to change the file into an "editable" state.

At the moment, I have to open every file i downloaded, which is very frustrating and if i do not do this, i will get a NULL file contains nothing when importing data.

please kindly help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996740/import-password-protected-xlsx-workbook-into-r

Answer (score 0):

Erm, i think i found a solution here, the file i downloaded from the internet is not password protected, it is just in protected mode.

so the answer to this is basically to disable the protected mode in excel. thanks for the answer anyway. @Hao