# How do you read a password protected excel file into r?

Tags: r, excel

How do you read a password protected excel file into r?

I have tried excel.link but its not available for R version 3.2.3 (My version)

I also tried RDCOMClient but it is also not available for R version 3.2.3

Comment: Have you tried these answers - http://stackoverflow.com/a/13997138

Comment: Yes I have.. the RDCOMClient can't be installed with my version of R so I'm looking for another library or a work round

Comment: what version of excel?  xlsx?

Comment: The most recent version of package XLConnect (0.2-12) adds this functionality.  On my windows 10 machine, running R 3.3.2, this fails with the error: Error: NoClassDefFoundError (Java): com/microsoft/schemas/office/x2006/encryption/EncryptionDocument$Factory

Comment: There is an open issue in the github repository for XLConnect: https://github.com/miraisolutions/xlconnect/issues/61

Comment: for those of us who don't want a Java dependency... any packages that can read password-protected xlsx files without extra Java installations?

Comment: @BrianD Hi Brian, I just read your comment. Don't know if you saw it already, but check my reply to the question.

Answer (score 20):

I just used `xl.read.file` from the `excel.link` package.

https://rdrr.io/cran/excel.link/man/xl.read.file.html

It was very straightforward.

Using the same test file from the previous answer (https://github.com/miraisolutions/xlconnect/files/794219/TestWorkbook.xlsx).

```
install.packages("excel.link")

library("excel.link")

dat <- xl.read.file("TestWorkbook.xlsx", password = "pass", write.res.password="pass")

dat
```

(The file I needed only had one password, unlike the test file, so I didn't need the last argument for my use.)

Comment: The xl.read.file function causes R to crash

Comment: Note that excel.link only works in Windows and MacOS (not Linux)

Comment: Doesn't work on MacOS either. Windows only. "*❗ Microsoft Windows and Microsoft Excel are required for this package.*"

Comment: Hi @MarkDavies, the above code works well. Your R is crashing probably because you open the same pass-worded excel file. When I opened the file while at the same time wanting to import, R crashed. But when I close the excel file and run the above code again, I was able to import the pass-worded excel file into R.

Answer (score 16):

[XLConnect](https://github.com/miraisolutions/xlconnect) (0.2-13) can now read password protected excel files

Install latest version of XLConnect and XLConnectJars (0.2-13)

```r
install.packages("XLConnect")
```

Install Unlimited Strength Java(TM) Cryptography Extension Policy
File
(necessary on OS X and Windows - not needed on Ubuntu linux with OpenJDK 1.8)

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

[How to install unlimited strength JCE for Java 8 in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37741142/how-to-install-unlimited-strength-jce-for-java-8-in-os-x)

```r
library(XLConnect)
```

Using [test file](https://github.com/miraisolutions/xlconnect/files/794219/TestWorkbook.xlsx):

```
wb <- loadWorkbook("TestWorkbook.xlsx", password="pass")
test <- readWorksheet(wb, "sheet1")

> data

  id value1 value2
1  1      1      5
2  2      2      4
3  3      3      3
4  4      4      2
5  5      5      1
```

Comment: Nice solution that works in linux too. Thanks! Note that XLConnectJars is no longer needed and was removed from CRAN: "Archived on 2020-03-26 as no longer used by XLConnect "

Answer (score 7):

To integrate the previous answers: I was looking to do the same and found that `excel.link` package has problems with the latest R version as of today and makes R crash.
`XLConnect` might work but it has complications from the need of extra installations that might be otherwise unnecessary for you.

I found that `xlsx::read.xlsx()` has a `password` argument and it worked just fine in my case.
For me this was the most practical solution.

Comment: xl.read.file crashes R (within RStudio) for me as well. (2021-05-10)

Comment: I tried `xlsx::read.xlsx()` but got the error`Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "newInstance", class,  : 
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`

Answer (score 2):

Building on Chris Andrews's answer, to avoid writing one's password in the code, one can also add in the `askForPassword` function. This will give a pop-up window asking to input the password when the code is run.

```
install.packages("excel.link")
install.packages("rstudioapi")

library("excel.link")

pw_message <- "Input password for excel sheet."

dat <- xl.read.file("TestWorkbook.xlsx", password = rstudioapi::askForPassword(pw_message))

dat
```

Comment: Good advice to keep passwords out of code. I like the keyring package for storing passwords.

Answer (score 1):

This is an older thread now I know, but I thought I would add this here in case it's useful.

I have been reading an Excel file into a Shiny application and found `xlsx::read.xlsx()` to be far slower than `excel.link::xl.read.file()` for my purposes.

However, using excel.link, I noticed that closing the app would not close the associated Excel process while xlsx did.

Using excel.link, it was necessary to include `system("TASKKILL /F /IM EXCEL.exe")` in order to force Excel to quit after the file had been read.