# How to install unlimited strength JCE for Java 8 in OS X?

Tags: java, macos, jce

I need to install the **Java Cryptography Extension** for `Java 8` in `OS X` / `mac OS`. It turns out the steps from the **README** file which came with the [installer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html) include instructions only for `Unix` and `Windows`, but not for `OS X` / `mac OS`. I tried to put the JAR files in `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security`, but it didn't work either. Do you know how can I install them?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

## Java 8 Update 161

As pointed out in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48604661) and in Oracle's [release notes for Java 8 Update 161](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u161-relnotes-4021379.html#JDK-8170157), unlimited cryptography is enabled by default since Update 161 and you shouldn't have to do anything if using a fresh installation of this version or higher.

## Java 8 Update 151

With Java 8 Update 151, Oracle included the same JCE mechanism into Java 8 that they already provided with Java 9. To enable JCE in Java 8 Update 151 or higher, just set the property

```
crypto.policy=unlimited
```

in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security`.

It's probably a good idea to remove the old policy JAR's if they were added earlier, as Oracle states in the [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u151-relnotes-3850493.html):

> Because the old JCE jurisdiction files are left in
>   /lib/security, they may not meet the latest security JAR
>   signing standards, which were refreshed in 6u131, 7u121, 8u111, and
>   later updates.

## Older Versions

Answers suggesting to install the JCE files via Homebrew won't work anymore, as the casks were deleted from the Homebrew repository after release of the Java 8 Update 151. If using an older version of Java 8, you'll have to put the JCE-Policy-JAR manually as described in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41002560/1225882).

Answer (score 84):

Note: As of Java JDK version 8u161 unlimited cryptography is enabled by default

## FOR MacOS user

If you are MacOS user, put the jars extracted from [jce_policy-8.zip](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html) if your java version is 8.* use below path (to put jars under it)

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/**< jdk_version_of_your_pc >**/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security
```

Comment: please see answer from [anothernode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1225882/anothernode) below. That is the correct solution for java 8 > 151 on/after Oct 2017.

Answer (score 13):

As of Java 8u152, unlimited strength can be enabled simply by setting `crypto.policy=unlimited` in the `java.security` file in

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<jdk_version>/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security
```

It's already in that file but commented out.

[image]

See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u152-relnotes-3850503.html#JDK-8157561

Comment: `The JDK JCE framework uses the unlimited policy files by default.` sourced from `jdk8_191`

Answer (score 12):

### For a Mac user (OS X) on Java 8:

> $ brew reinstall java8

As of JDK 1.8u151 it is not necessary to download the JCE libraries separately. Simply edit

> $JDK_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security

and uncomment the line:

`crypto.policy=unlimited`

This will enable the unlimited strength JCE.

[JDK 1.8u151 Release Notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8all-relnotes-2226344.html#R180_151)

Answer (score 8):

As of Java JDK version 8u161 [unlimited cryptography is enabled by default](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u161-relnotes-4021379.html#JDK-8170157) and the other suggested methods should no longer be necessary (unless you want to disable it).

This change also [appears to be included in other major JDK versions from JDK 6 to JDK 9.](https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8170157)

Answer (score 6):

As you did not explain what is your problem here some guesses.

1. Using an internet search engine you probably would have found this page http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html
2. you might have downloaded this file `jce_policy-8.zip`
3. maybe you would have unzipped it and had a look into directory `UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK8/`
4. maybe the file `README.txt` would have attracted your interest

If all of those steps would have been true, then you would have found

```
3)  Install the unlimited strength policy JAR files.

In case you later decide to revert to the original "strong" but
limited policy versions, first make a copy of the original JCE
policy files (US_export_policy.jar and local_policy.jar). Then
replace the strong policy files with the unlimited strength
versions extracted in the previous step.

The standard place for JCE jurisdiction policy JAR files is:

    <java-home>/lib/security           [Unix]
    <java-home>\lib\security           [Windows]
```

You can assume that the location on OSX is the same as for the listed systems.

Comment: @JonDoe297 `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/< jdk_version_of_your_pc >/Contents/Home/jre` that is your `<java-home>`. And when you add `/lib/security` you have the path from prasshant.

Answer (score 5):

For later versions of macOS (e.g., Sierra), Oracle Java is installed in two locations depending on if you install the JRE or JDK.

- JRE: `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/`
- JDK: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.x.x_xxx.jdk/Contents/Home/`

  - If you install the JDK, it will also install the JRE at the JRE location listed above.

The JRE allows you to double-click to open jars from the Finder and run Java in the browser. The JRE does not come with the `java` binary, so if you want to run any of the typical Java commands, you must install the JDK. More at https://java.com/en/download/faq/yosemite_java.xml.

All this to say, when installing then unlimited strength JCE files, install them in both directories listed above to get consistent behavior.

Answer (score 4):

if you're a windows user:

download the most updated JCE on http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

extract zip file and copy the two jar files in the following directory

\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\lib\security