# Jose4j validate signature alg RS256 against encryption algorithm

Tags: jose4j

The JWT is signed with RS256, and I am using jose4j to verify JWT signature. In one of user environment which I do not have access, it generates this unexpected exception:

> org.jose4j.lang.InvalidAlgorithmException: RS256 is an unknown,
>   unsupported or unavailable alg algorithm (not one of [RSA1_5,
>   RSA-OAEP, RSA-OAEP-256, dir, A128KW, A192KW, A256KW, ECDH-ES,
>   ECDH-ES+A128KW, ECDH-ES+A192KW, ECDH-ES+A256KW, PBES2-HS256+A128KW,
>   PBES2-HS384+A192KW, PBES2-HS512+A256KW, A128GCMKW, A192GCMKW,
>   A256GCMKW])

Looks like the signature algorithm is incorrectly validated against Key encryption algorithm. Note that my codes only do signature validation, and do not have any logic for decryption/encryption. This only happens in one user environment, and I can not access or recreate it locally.

Does anyone ever see such a problem? or can give me a hint to debug it?

Comment: It turns out the problem is in the received token content. A un-encrypted JWT has three parts, "p1.p2.p3". The token I received is "p1.p2.p3 p1.p2.p3", which becomes an encrypted JWT.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37741142/how-to-install-unlimited-strength-jce-for-java-8-in-os-x/45055461

Answer (score 3):

The `JwtConsumer` looks at the JWT string it is processing and attempts to determine whether it's a JWS or JWE based on the format.  JWSs have three segments separated by two period ('.') characters like `<header>.<payload>.<signature>` while JWEs have five segments separated by four period ('.') characters like `<header>.<encrypted-key>.<IV>.<ciphertext>.<authentication-tag>`.

It would appear that you've somehow gotten a malformed JWT that has a JWS header but five encoded segments separated by four period characters. The `JwtConsumer` will first see the structure with four dots and attempt to process it as a JWE. Then it fails when it sees a non JWE alg header value. I have no idea how the JWT might have gotten malformed like that but that's almost certainly what the error message means.

Comment: Thanks Brian! That is what exactly happens here. The received unencrypted JWT is supposed to be like "p1.p2.p3". The token I received is "p1.p2.p3 p1.p2.p3", which becomes an encrypted JWT.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error because I did not have the JCE (Java Cryptography Extension) in my JDK. (I assume, many people can google this question because of the same issue).
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37741142/how-to-install-unlimited-strength-jce-for-java-8-in-os-x/45055461) you can find how to install it on MacOS.