# How to unlock a password protected excel file using R and VBA

Tags: python, r, vba, passwords, unlock

I have some password protected files received from my colleagues on a daily basis and I would like to unlock them programmatically so that I can read them do build my reports.

In Python I was able to unlock files with the `win32com.client` default package. How about R?

Here's how I did it in Python,

```
def unprotect_xlsx(filename, pwd):
    try:
        xcl = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
        wb = xcl.Workbooks.Open(filename, False, False, None, pwd)
        wb.Unprotect(pwd)
        wb.UnprotectSharing(pwd)

        xcl.DisplayAlerts = False
        wb.SaveAs(filename.split('.xlsx')[0]+"_unlocked"+".xlsx", None, '', '')
        xcl.Quit()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:")
        print(e)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you read a password protected excel file into r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35852722/how-do-you-read-a-password-protected-excel-file-into-r)

Answer (score 2):

However, if you are using R, you must have come acroos this `RDCOMClient` library but it is merely an interface to work with a variety of clients without exactly having a built-in function that can do the unlocking.

So I had a workaround. I used `RDCOMClient` to interface with an macro-enabled excel VBA file which does the unlocking.

I created the macro-enabled excel (macro_unlocker.xlsm), enabled the developer option and wrote this VBA code which will take in the filename and password from R and unlock the file as an Excel program,

```
Public Sub unlock_file(filename, pwd)
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim filename_path As String

filename_path = filename

'MsgBox filename_path & " " & pwd
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename:=filename, Password:=pwd)

save_filepath = Split(filename, ".xlsx")(0) & "_unlocked.xlsx"
wb.SaveAs filename:=save_filepath, Password:=""

End Sub
```

The `RDCOMClient` interfaces with the VBA by passing the arguments to the VBA script. It unlocked the file by setting the password as an empty string.

Then in R, I can write a function to pass the arguments to it. And this is what I have, I put this in an external R file called `myUtils.R` just to make things neater,

```
unlock_xlsx <- function(filename, pwd){
  if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
  pacman::p_load(devtools)

  devtools::install_github("dkyleward/RDCOMClient")
  library(RDCOMClient)

  # Open a specific workbook in Excel:
  xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")

  xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()

  xlWbk$Open(paste(getwd(), "/<utils folder>/macro_unlocker.xlsm",sep=""))

  # this line of code might be necessary if you want to see your spreadsheet:
  xlApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE

  # Run the macro:
  xlApp$Run("unlock_file", filename, pwd)

  # Close the workbook and quit the app:
  xlWbk$Close(FALSE)
  xlApp$Quit()

}
```

So finally to run the functions and the VBA macro in R so that I can unlock the files programmatically and do my work I wrote this in R,

```
# call in myUtils.R where the function unlock_xlsx resides
source(paste(getwd(), "./myUtils.R", sep=""))

# file to unlock
password_locked_file_FILEPATH <- Sys.glob(file.path("<sub-folder>", "<sub-folder>","<an_excel.xlsx>"))

# send the file_filepath to the function
file_to_unlock <- paste("../", password_locked_file_FILEPATH, sep="")
password_locked_file_pwd <- "<password>"

# result will be suffixed with '_unlocked' followed by '.xlsx'
unlock_xlsx(filename = file_to_unlock, pwd = password_locked_file_pwd)
```

Tada! The file is unlocked and saved with the suffix `_unlocked`. And you can definitely cycle through your files to be unlocked and provide the corresponding passwords and everything would work like clockwork.

This works as long you have R and Excel installed in your machine.

Note: I do understand there are some issues with the installation of `RDCOMClient` its not compatible with the latest R version 3.6. I had a workaround by installing `dkyleward/RDCOMClient` and it installed perfectly well on a Windows machine but failed on MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following approach :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE

path_To_Excel_File <- "D:\\excel_File.xlsx"
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_To_Excel_File, password = "xxx")
xlWbk$SaveAs("D:\\excel_File_Unlocked.xlsx", password = "")
```

It is an answer very similar to an already given answer. However, it is more simple from my point of view.