# open a OneDrive file with r

Tags: r, shiny, sharepoint-online, onedrive, microsoft365r

Im tring to create a shiny app that read and online onedrive xlsx file and show some things, but for the moment Im unable to read the onedrive xlsx file, I already explore the Microsoft365R and I can conect to my onedrive and I even can open the fil but... what it does is from r open a tab in chrome with the excel file.

I need the file in the local enviroment of r.. this its beacause the shiny app must be deploy in a web server, that every time the app runs it reads the update the file.

```
library(Microsfot365R)

odb <- get_business_onedrive()
odb$open_file("lcursos.xlsx")
```

Also this its a business account, so I also have to put the username and key to acces each file, that its beacause use the simple url doesnt work, it says Error 403 FORBIDEEN.

Any ideas?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you tried to create the shiny project inside OneDrive?

Comment: No. But I didn't see how this can help. Beacause once the app will be bundle the file will be fixed. I need that the shiny app load the file from a could service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2021, I was unable to do follow your answer, so I use Google `googledrive` library in that time to solve the problem. Now I face the same challenge, so I checking it, and I find the way to solve it.

Thanks

```
library(Microsoft365R)
library(AzureGraph)

od <- get_business_onedrive()
od$list_files()

dest <- tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx")

od$download_file("Documentos/lcursos.xlsx", dest=dest,overwrite = T)

open_in_r<-readxl::read_excel(dest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `download_file()` method to download the file to your local machine:

```r
odb$download_file("lcursos.xlsx")
```

You can set the location of the download with the `dest` argument. Once it's downloaded, open it with the xls reader package of your choice. I suggest either openxlsx or readxl.

Note that if your file is password protected, your options are limited. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35852722/how-do-you-read-a-password-protected-excel-file-into-r) for possible solutions.

Comment: There is a way to load directly into R?

Comment: What if I need to read the file inside a Shiny app deployed to shinyapps.io? The download_file option wouldn't work (it wouldn't know where to download things) and what is actually needed (as per question from Manuel) is to load the information directly into the environment instead of saving it somewhere and then load it.

Comment: @MatteoCastagna every R session, even one running in shinyapps.io, has a filesystem available to it. Locating a file in that filesystem is an exercise left to the reader

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But how can I do a code login in the `get_business_onedrive()`, that its my issue with the solution given by @HongOoi, in my pc when I use the `get_business_onedrive()` funcition and it open a new tab and I allow the conection, but it dont work on the shinyapps.io. So how can I code the login using the Microsoft360R ?

Comment: @MANUELALEJANDRORODRIGUEZORT see my answer to Matteo [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69050422/474349)