# Open .rda file in a Shiny app uploaded to shinyapps.io

Tags: r, sharepoint, shiny, microsoft365r

I am trying to achieve the following:

1. Deploy a Shiny app to shinyapps.io
2. On open, the app connects to Sharepoint
3. Downloads and opens a .rda file stored there. That file contains proprietary data where only people with the relevant credentials can get access to.

This allows me to separate access to the app from access to the data (only if you have the relevant credentials you can get the data file - the .rda). It also means an upload of a much slimmer set of information to the shinyapps.io servers.

It all works fine within R-studio as the download operation sticks the .rda into the local folder and the load operation takes the objects serialized there into the environment.

It fails (predictably) once the app is deployed to shinyapps.io: I suspect the "download" stops meaning anything.
Ideally there should be a "open" action which opens the .rda and then takes the relevant objects into the environment. I really couldn't find it.

This is the code that works within R-Studio (I cannot obviously share the precise details of the Sharepoint site), any help figuring out the correct workflow strategy so it could work on shinyapps.io would be really appreciated.

```
library(Microsoft365R)

site <- get_sharepoint_site(site_id = "idOfTheSharepointSite")
docs <- site$get_drive()

docs$download_file("Stuff/DelSet.Rda", overwrite = T)

load("DelSet.Rda")
```

**EDIT**

The actual problem is not the management of the file itself (the comment below should address that). It's the autentication on Sharepoint within Shinyapps.io.
This barebone app fails as well (while working as expected on R-studio).

```
library(shiny)
library(Microsoft365R)

site <- get_sharepoint_site(site_id = "IDofMySite")
docs <- site$get_drive()

ui <- fluidPage(h5("Hello world!"))

server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Try downloading to the temp directory: `dest <- tempfile(fileext=".rda"); docs$download_file(*, dest=dest); load(dest)`

Comment: I think I understand what you are suggesting. I modified it slightly (I have multiple .Rda files and I need specifically that one). 

I did: `dest <- tempfile("whatever.Rda"); docs$download_file("Stuff/DelSet.Rda", dest=dest); load(dest)`. 
It works in R-studio, not in shinyapps.io.
My current guess is that it's a problem with the Sharepoint autentication which is satisfied on my PC (where I run R-studio) but not on shinyapps.io servers. Just a wild guess.

Comment: @HongOoi That (comment above) is actually the problem.
I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @HongOoi is https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AzureAuth/vignettes/shiny.html what I need to implement by any chance?

Comment: That vignette is basically what you need to do. Note that you must create an app registration of your own, you can't use the builtin app ID from Microsoft365R (it assumes you're running it on the local machine). I have a specific vignette on running Microsoft365R in Shiny in the works

Comment: Related: https://github.com/Azure/Microsoft365R/issues/79

Comment: I am now out of my depth I am afraid. I tried a version of what the vignette is detailing, but I suspect I fail because I don't know the "app ID". I am also not an admin on the Sharepoint side and that means I would need to tell an admin precisely what to do in that respect. Not sure how to tell them about that requirement in terms of "app registration".
When you say "register your app with Azure" is the app the Shiny app living in shinyapps.io (eg, https://mcastagnaa.shinyapps.io/nameOfTheApp) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236746/discussion-between-matteo-castagna-and-hong-ooi).

Comment: I have a draft vignette written up: https://github.com/Azure/Microsoft365R/blob/shiny-auth/vignettes/shiny.Rmd, comments appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Normally when you call the Microsoft365R functions like `get_sharepoint_site()`, they authenticate using a builtin app registration ID that assumes the code is running on your local machine. This won't work when your code is on a remote server, like shinyapps.io. Instead you have to register your app with Azure, and use the resulting app ID when authenticating.

The process is basically:

- Create an app registration that contains information about your site, including the redirect URI (your site address), and who is allowed to use it (everyone or only people in your org). You can do this in the Azure portal, or with the CLI.
- Give the app registration the necessary permissions for working with MS365. They are all Microsoft Graph permissions, and the scopes have the base URI `https://graph.microsoft.com/*`.
- In your Shiny UI script, call build_authorization_uri with the required scopes, your tenant, and your app ID
- In the server script, call get_azure_token and pass it the authcode, as shown in the AzureAuth Shiny vignette
- Use the token in your call to `get_sharepoint_site`.

A draft vignette describing the process and providing a simple Shiny app skeleton is here: https://github.com/Azure/Microsoft365R/blob/master/vignettes/shiny.Rmd