# R Import password protected Excel file on Linux

Tags: r, excel, password-protection

I want to import a password protected Excel file with R on Linux. There exists already a solution with the `excel.link` package:
[How do you read a password protected excel file into r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35852722/how-do-you-read-a-password-protected-excel-file-into-r)
However, in my case it's not possible, because this package is only available for Windows users. I can't find a package that offers me an import function with a password option.
Can someone help me?

```
# Here is an example excel document:

path <- "https://github.com/miraisolutions/xlconnect/files/794219/TestWorkbook.xlsx"

password <- "pass"
```

Comment: Here is an answer that works in Linux too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43915133/2886003

Answer (score 0):

The R package XLConnect works on Linux. Hence, you should be able to open your Excel file with the following code :

```
library(XLConnect)

download.file(url = "https://github.com/miraisolutions/xlconnect/files/794219/TestWorkbook.xlsx",
              destfile = "D:/TestWorkbook.xlsx", mode = "wb")

wb <- loadWorkbook(filename = "D:/TestWorkbook.xlsx", create = FALSE, password = "pass")
```